# Distortion when using browser zoom, proven ways to avoid this?

Tags: css, zooming

I got a weird behavior when using browser zoom.

In standard mode it looks really nice:

[image]

When zooming in, all elements shift a little bit, and the result is ugly (missing top border line, picture with z-index smaller than this one gets visible just below the z-index level and the element below it):

[image]

What is a proven good way to avoid these effects?

The element is rather complex with relative and absolute positioning together with z-indexing.

Stop the user from zooming all together best solution?

Comment: You should probably provide some code. It's impossible to figure out the problem if we can't replicate it and don't even know if you're doing that with CSS, or images, borders, text-decoration etc. Also, disabling user zoom because it creates some artifacts in your design is probably the most selfish reason I've heard for wanting to disable zoom (not that you can really do that effectively anyway).

Comment: @ChristianVarga a different example in this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlKJs 
if you zoom in, actually the vertical line next to projekte becomes 2 pixels wide.

Comment: **Projekte** has a `vertical-line-header-right` inside of it, and **Visual Columns** has a `vertical-line-header-left` div inside of it. So that line is not becoming 2 pixels wide; it's simply displaying both of those elements next to each other instead of on top of each other (due to percentage rounding). You really shouldn't be using extra HTML elements for borders when you could just simply use CSS `border` properties. The more complicated you make it, the more issue you'll have.

Comment: @ChristianVarga hmm well but the border is not what I am looking for, is it? since the design would look differently. It is not a fully sized border

Comment: Then use pseudo-elements, or nested elements with padding on the parent and a border on the child. Using extra markup for borders is never the right solution. Ever. Anyway, what I said still stands - you have 2 elements overlapping each other, which go out of position when zoomed. If you just remove one of them (considering 2 elements overlapping each other is completely useless), you'll fix your 2px wide border issue, which is one step closer to fixing your problem.